# How to check for a certain type of variable in an input

Tags: java, input, double, java.util.scanner

I am new at programming so sorry if this is a stupid question, but I cant find the answer anywhere.

I have a scanner that asks for the answer of a math problem (the scanner expects a double to be the input). Naturally, most people would enter in a number as an answer, but if they put in something else (that can't be converted to a double) I am supposed to give them a message saying to put it in decimal form. The only problem is I am having a hard time figuring out out to tell the computer if (answer != double) then print out "blah, blah, blah". Currently if you input a letter or something, it gives a computer generated error message in red that I don't want. Is there a way to tell it to print out the message I want instead?

This is a small part of my program that contains the scanner in question:

```
if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
        System.out.print("What is the solution to the problem: " + correctRange + " + " + correctRange2 + " = ");
        // make the user answers a double variable
        double answer;
        answer = scnr.nextDouble();

        double solution;
        solution = correctRange + correctRange2;


            // make a variable that is determined by if the answer is close
            // enough
            boolean close = ((solution + Config.CLOSE_ENOUGH) >= answer
                    && answer >= (solution - Config.CLOSE_ENOUGH));

            // give different responses based on if the user's answer was
            // close
            if (close) {
                System.out.println("That is correct!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The correct solution is " + solution + ".");
            }
```

Comment: [`scanner.hasNextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()) returns `true` if a call to `scanner.nextDouble()` will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Scanner.hasNextDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--) e.g.

```
if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    double d = scanner.nextDouble();
    // do something with d
} else {
    scanner.nextLine(); // discard the line
    System.err.println("Please enter a number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either do

```
 try{
     result = scanner.nextDouble();
 }catch (InputMismatchException ex){
     System.out.println("blah blah");
 }
```

or and even better

```
if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    result = scanner.nextDouble();
} else {
    System.err.println("blah blah");
    scanner.nextLine(); // discard the line
}
```